# Set pricing on the assigned to the company

Tags: magento2, price-rules, magento2-b2b

While running the Magenta Commerce edition using the B2B module, an administrator has been asked to set pricing on the assigned to the company.

**Which two actions are taken to accomplish this? Choose 2 answers**

> 1)Set a price rule in Marketing -> Catalog price rules
>
> 2)Set pricing on your shared catalog
>
> 3)Set prices to a customer group
>
> 4)Set pricing rules in companies

Answer (score 0):

1 and 2.
1: You can add a price rule and assign it to a customer group where a company also belongs to.
2: Most logical solution. Create shared catalogs per discount and assign a company to one of these groups.
3 is not possible because you can't set prices on customer groups.
4 is not possible because you can't set price rules on companies.